# Can't use UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification as name in NSNotificaitonCenter's addObserver: selector: name: object: method

Tags: ios

I copied a file into a new project and it seemed to be working fine. This code was working in the old project too, but then all of a sudden (in the new project), I'm getting several errors that I can't figure out.

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(saveBookmarks)
               name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
             object:nil];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(saveBookmarks)
               name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
             object:nil];
```

Using the name `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` gives me the error "Use of undeclared identifier UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification."

Using the name `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` gives me the error message "Use of undeclared identifier UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification" and attempts to change the name to `NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification,` which clears the error, but it's not what I need?!

I know that this code was working before, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it's not working now.

Comment: check the class that you used this method  has #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

Answer (score 12):

You are probably just missing UIKit headers:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, in my new project, I need to import the AppDelegate.h file. This wasn't necessary in my old project (which ironically still works), but it is in this new one.

Comment: Yes, se_puede_dec 's method is right, it works for my project which also has this issue. I imported AppDelegate.h file. Any people knows why? It is so weird.